# WELD-001408: Unsatisfied dependencies for type Employee with qualifiers @Default

Tags: jsf, cdi, weld

I got the following error when deploying to Glassfish on Netbeans. This is the first time I am trying to CDI. I have read all the post on this issue up to no help.

Log:

```
Info:   visiting unvisited references
Info:   visiting unvisited references
Info:   visiting unvisited references
Info:   visiting unvisited references
Info:   Enity.Test.Employee actually got transformed
Info:   EclipseLink, version: Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.2.v20140319-9ad6abd
Info:   file:/C:/Users/Bala/Documents/NetBeansProjects/TestAppl/dist/gfdeploy/TestAppl/TestAppl-ejb_jar/_TestAppl-ejbPU login successful
Info:   Portable JNDI names for EJB EmployeeEJB: [java:global/TestAppl/TestAppl-ejb/EmployeeEJB, java:global/TestAppl/TestAppl-ejb/EmployeeEJB!SessionlessEmployee.EmployeeEJB]
WARN:   WELD-000411: Observer method [BackedAnnotatedMethod] public org.glassfish.jms.injection.JMSCDIExtension.processAnnotatedType(@Observes ProcessAnnotatedType<Object>) receives events for all annotated types. Consider restricting events using @WithAnnotations or a generic type with bounds.
WARN:   WELD-000411: Observer method [BackedAnnotatedMethod] org.glassfish.sse.impl.ServerSentEventCdiExtension.processAnnotatedType(@Observes ProcessAnnotatedType<Object>, BeanManager) receives events for all annotated types. Consider restricting events using @WithAnnotations or a generic type with bounds.
WARN:   WELD-000411: Observer method [BackedAnnotatedMethod] private org.glassfish.jersey.gf.cdi.internal.CdiComponentProvider.processAnnotatedType(@Observes ProcessAnnotatedType<Object>) receives events for all annotated types. Consider restricting events using @WithAnnotations or a generic type with bounds.
WARN:   WELD-000411: Observer method [BackedAnnotatedMethod] public org.glassfish.jms.injection.JMSCDIExtension.processAnnotatedType(@Observes ProcessAnnotatedType<Object>) receives events for all annotated types. Consider restricting events using @WithAnnotations or a generic type with bounds.
WARN:   WELD-000411: Observer method [BackedAnnotatedMethod] org.glassfish.sse.impl.ServerSentEventCdiExtension.processAnnotatedType(@Observes ProcessAnnotatedType<Object>, BeanManager) receives events for all annotated types. Consider restricting events using @WithAnnotations or a generic type with bounds.
WARN:   WELD-000411: Observer method [BackedAnnotatedMethod] private org.glassfish.jersey.gf.cdi.internal.CdiComponentProvider.processAnnotatedType(@Observes ProcessAnnotatedType<Object>) receives events for all annotated types. Consider restricting events using @WithAnnotations or a generic type with bounds.
Severe:   Exception during lifecycle processing
org.glassfish.deployment.common.DeploymentException: CDI deployment failure:WELD-001408: Unsatisfied dependencies for type Employee with qualifiers @Default
  at injection point [BackedAnnotatedField] @Inject private Managedbean.Testapp.employeeController.employee
  at Managedbean.Testapp.employeeController.employee(employeeController.java:0)
    at org.glassfish.weld.WeldDeployer.event(WeldDeployer.java:234)
    at org.glassfish.kernel.event.EventsImpl.send(EventsImpl.java:131)
    at org.glassfish.internal.data.ApplicationInfo.load(ApplicationInfo.java:328)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:496)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:219)
    at org.glassfish.deployment.admin.DeployCommand.execute(DeployCommand.java:491)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2$1.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:539)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2$1.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:535)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:356)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:534)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$3.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:565)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$3.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:557)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:356)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:556)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1464)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.access$1300(CommandRunnerImpl.java:109)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1846)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1722)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.doCommand(AdminAdapter.java:534)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.onMissingResource(AdminAdapter.java:224)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.StaticHttpHandlerBase.service(StaticHttpHandlerBase.java:189)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:459)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:167)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:201)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:175)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:235)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:284)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:201)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:133)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:561)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:117)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:56)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:137)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:565)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:545)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.jboss.weld.exceptions.DeploymentException: WELD-001408: Unsatisfied dependencies for type Employee with qualifiers @Default
  at injection point [BackedAnnotatedField] @Inject private Managedbean.Testapp.employeeController.employee
  at Managedbean.Testapp.employeeController.employee(employeeController.java:0)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateInjectionPointForDeploymentProblems(Validator.java:370)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateInjectionPoint(Validator.java:291)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateGeneralBean(Validator.java:134)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateRIBean(Validator.java:165)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateBean(Validator.java:529)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateBeans(Validator.java:515)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateDeployment(Validator.java:490)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.WeldStartup.validateBeans(WeldStartup.java:419)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.WeldBootstrap.validateBeans(WeldBootstrap.java:90)
    at org.glassfish.weld.WeldDeployer.event(WeldDeployer.java:225)
    ... 41 more

Severe:   Exception while loading the app
Severe:   Undeployment failed for context /TestAppl-war
Info:   file:/C:/Users/Bala/Documents/NetBeansProjects/TestAppl/dist/gfdeploy/TestAppl/TestAppl-ejb_jar/_TestAppl-ejbPU logout successful
Severe:   Exception while loading the app : CDI deployment failure:WELD-001408: Unsatisfied dependencies for type Employee with qualifiers @Default
  at injection point [BackedAnnotatedField] @Inject private Managedbean.Testapp.employeeController.employee
  at Managedbean.Testapp.employeeController.employee(employeeController.java:0)
org.jboss.weld.exceptions.DeploymentException: WELD-001408: Unsatisfied dependencies for type Employee with qualifiers @Default
  at injection point [BackedAnnotatedField] @Inject private Managedbean.Testapp.employeeController.employee
  at Managedbean.Testapp.employeeController.employee(employeeController.java:0)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateInjectionPointForDeploymentProblems(Validator.java:370)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateInjectionPoint(Validator.java:291)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateGeneralBean(Validator.java:134)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateRIBean(Validator.java:165)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateBean(Validator.java:529)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateBeans(Validator.java:515)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateDeployment(Validator.java:490)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.WeldStartup.validateBeans(WeldStartup.java:419)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.WeldBootstrap.validateBeans(WeldBootstrap.java:90)
    at org.glassfish.weld.WeldDeployer.event(WeldDeployer.java:225)
    at org.glassfish.kernel.event.EventsImpl.send(EventsImpl.java:131)
    at org.glassfish.internal.data.ApplicationInfo.load(ApplicationInfo.java:328)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:496)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:219)
    at org.glassfish.deployment.admin.DeployCommand.execute(DeployCommand.java:491)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2$1.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:539)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2$1.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:535)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:356)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:534)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$3.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:565)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$3.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:557)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:356)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:556)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1464)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.access$1300(CommandRunnerImpl.java:109)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1846)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1722)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.doCommand(AdminAdapter.java:534)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.onMissingResource(AdminAdapter.java:224)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.StaticHttpHandlerBase.service(StaticHttpHandlerBase.java:189)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:459)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:167)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:201)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:175)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:235)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:284)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:201)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:133)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:561)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:117)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:56)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:137)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:565)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:545)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

My program code:

TestAppl-war

Index.xhtml

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
      xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core">
    <h:head>
        <title>Facelet Title</title>
    </h:head>
    <h:body>

       <h:form>
         <h:panelGrid columns="2" >
         <h:outputLabel value="First Name : "/>
         <h:inputText value="#{employeeController.employee.firstname}" />
         <h:outputLabel value="Last Name : "/>
         <h:inputText value="#{employeeController.employee.lastName}"/>
         <h:outputLabel value="Date of Birth : "/>
         <h:inputText value="#{employeeController.employee.dob}">
              <f:convertDateTime pattern="dd/mm/yyyy"/>
         </h:inputText>
         <h:outputLabel value="Phone : "/>
         <h:inputText value="#{employeeController.employee.phone}"/>
         <h:outputLabel value="Email : "/>
         <h:inputText value="#{employeeController.employee.email}"/>
         </h:panelGrid>
       <h:commandButton value="Add New Employee"                                  
                        action="#{employeeController.addNewEmployee()}"/>            
         </h:form>
    </h:body>
</html>
```

employeeController.java

```
    package Managedbean.Testapp;

 import Enity.Test.Employee;
import SessionlessEmployee.EmployeeEJB;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Date;
import javax.enterprise.context.RequestScoped;
import javax.inject.Inject;


import javax.inject.Named;

/**
 *
 * @author Bala
 */
@Named(value = "employeeController")
@RequestScoped
public class employeeController implements Serializable {
    private Employee employee = new Employee();
    @Inject private EmployeeEJB employeeEJB;

    /**
     * Creates a new instance of employeeController
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private String firstname;

    private String middlename;

    private String lastname;

    private Date dob;

    private String phone;

    private String email;

    public employeeController() {


    }


    public void setFirstname(String firstname) {
        this.firstname = firstname;
    }



    public void setMiddlename(String middlename) {
        this.middlename = middlename;
    }



    public void setLastname(String lastname) {
        this.lastname = lastname;
    }



    public void setDob(Date dob) {
        this.dob = dob;
    }



    public void setPhone(String phone) {
        this.phone = phone;
    }


    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

     public void addNewEmployee() {
        employee = employeeEJB.addNew(employee);

    }



}
```

EmployeeEJB

```
package SessionlessEmployee;

import Enity.Test.Employee;
import java.util.List;
import javax.ejb.Stateless;
import javax.ejb.LocalBean;
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.PersistenceContext;
import javax.persistence.TypedQuery;


@Stateless
@LocalBean
public class EmployeeEJB {
    @PersistenceContext(unitName = "TestAppl-ejbPU")
    private EntityManager entityManager;

       public List<Employee> findEmployees(){
              TypedQuery<Employee> query = entityManager.createNamedQuery("findAllEmployees", Employee.class);        
              return query.getResultList();
       }

       public Employee addNew(Employee employee) {
              entityManager.persist(employee);
              return employee;
       }

}
```

Employee

```
package Enity.Test;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Date;
import javax.persistence.Basic;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.NamedQueries;
import javax.persistence.NamedQuery;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.persistence.Temporal;
import javax.persistence.TemporalType;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;
import javax.validation.constraints.Size;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;


@Entity
@Table(name = "EMPLOYEE")
@XmlRootElement
@NamedQueries({
    @NamedQuery(name = "Employee.findAll", query = "SELECT e FROM Employee e"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Employee.findById", query = "SELECT e FROM Employee e WHERE e.id = :id"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Employee.findByFirstname", query = "SELECT e FROM Employee e WHERE e.firstname = :firstname"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Employee.findByMiddlename", query = "SELECT e FROM Employee e WHERE e.middlename = :middlename"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Employee.findByLastname", query = "SELECT e FROM Employee e WHERE e.lastname = :lastname"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Employee.findByDob", query = "SELECT e FROM Employee e WHERE e.dob = :dob"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Employee.findByPhone", query = "SELECT e FROM Employee e WHERE e.phone = :phone"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Employee.findByEmail", query = "SELECT e FROM Employee e WHERE e.email = :email")})
public class Employee implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "ID")
    private Integer id;
    @Size(max = 100)
    @Column(name = "FIRSTNAME")
    private String firstname;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 1, max = 100)
    @Column(name = "MIDDLENAME")
    private String middlename;
    @Size(max = 100)
    @Column(name = "LASTNAME")
    private String lastname;
    @Column(name = "DOB")
    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    private Date dob;
    // @Pattern(regexp="^\\(?(\\d{3})\\)?[- ]?(\\d{3})[- ]?(\\d{4})$", message="Invalid phone/fax format, should be as xxx-xxx-xxxx")//if the field contains phone or fax number consider using this annotation to enforce field validation
    @Size(max = 10)
    @Column(name = "PHONE")
    private String phone;
    // @Pattern(regexp="[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\\.[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*@(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\\.)+[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?", message="Invalid email")//if the field contains email address consider using this annotation to enforce field validation
    @Size(max = 100)
    @Column(name = "EMAIL")
    private String email;

    public Employee() {
    }

    public Employee(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Employee(Integer id, String middlename) {
        this.id = id;
        this.middlename = middlename;
    }

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getFirstname() {
        return firstname;
    }

    public void setFirstname(String firstname) {
        this.firstname = firstname;
    }

    public String getMiddlename() {
        return middlename;
    }

    public void setMiddlename(String middlename) {
        this.middlename = middlename;
    }

    public String getLastname() {
        return lastname;
    }

    public void setLastname(String lastname) {
        this.lastname = lastname;
    }

    public Date getDob() {
        return dob;
    }

    public void setDob(Date dob) {
        this.dob = dob;
    }

    public String getPhone() {
        return phone;
    }

    public void setPhone(String phone) {
        this.phone = phone;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int hash = 0;
        hash += (id != null ? id.hashCode() : 0);
        return hash;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object object) {
        // TODO: Warning - this method won't work in the case the id fields are not set
        if (!(object instanceof Employee)) {
            return false;
        }
        Employee other = (Employee) object;
        if ((this.id == null && other.id != null) || (this.id != null && !this.id.equals(other.id))) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Enity.Test.Employee[ id=" + id + " ]";
    }

}
```

Table

```
create table "Database".EMPLOYEE
(
    ID INTEGER not null primary key,
    FIRSTNAME VARCHAR(100),
    MIDDLENAME VARCHAR(100) not null,
    LASTNAME VARCHAR(100),
    DOB DATE,
    PHONE VARCHAR(10),
    EMAIL VARCHAR(100)
)
```

beans.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/beans_1_1.xsd"
       bean-discovery-mode="all">
</beans>
```

This is auto generated source when I deploy

Employee_.java

```
 package Enity.Test;

import java.util.Date;
import javax.annotation.Generated;
import javax.persistence.metamodel.SingularAttribute;
import javax.persistence.metamodel.StaticMetamodel;

@Generated(value="EclipseLink-2.5.2.v20140319-rNA", date="2015-04-06T09:18:49")
@StaticMetamodel(Employee.class)
public class Employee_ { 

    public static volatile SingularAttribute<Employee, Integer> id;
    public static volatile SingularAttribute<Employee, String> phone;
    public static volatile SingularAttribute<Employee, String> middlename;
    public static volatile SingularAttribute<Employee, String> email;
    public static volatile SingularAttribute<Employee, Date> dob;
    public static volatile SingularAttribute<Employee, String> lastname;
    public static volatile SingularAttribute<Employee, String> firstname;

}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: This class name `employeeController` is not according to the basic Java naming conventions. It should be written in camel-case such as `EmployeeController`. (In JSF, there is essentially only one controller which is `FacesServlet`. All other managed beans which you are supposed to design in your application are essentially models and not controllers as you seem to have assumed from the name itself - `EmployeeController`).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This line of code in EmployeeController is causing the exception to be thrown
`private @Inject Employee employee = new Employee();`. You are trying to inject Employee but this isn't a bean which CDI can inject. If you drop the @Inject annotation it should resolve the problem.

As a side note `private @Inject EmployeeEJB employeeEJB;` should be annotated with `@EJB` rather than `@Inject`

Comment: He/she is also importing a wrong annotation `javax.faces.bean.RequestScoped` (JSF native) instead of importing it from `javax.enterprise.context.RequestScoped` (a CDI artifact). (`@Inject` is basically preferred over `@EJB` (local). Since `EmployEJB` is a stateless local EJB, it is perfectly legitimate to inject it using `@Inject` in CDI managed beans. This line (a JPA entity - the culprit) `private @Inject Employee employee = new Employee();` is entirely not needed in managed beans. Implementing the `java.io.Serializable` interface on a request scoped managed bean is utterly superfluous).

Comment: Thank you both . I was able to make progress :) no more errors. and I got a better understanding. I had to download cdi library and add it in.  Can you give a bit more detail on "Implementing the java.io.Serializable interface on a request scoped managed bean is utterly superfluous). " ? I have updated the employeeController however my next step is finding out why the data was not written to the table :)

Comment: Your answer solves @workingman's problem, but learn that CDI can inject POJOs ([reference](http://www.adam-bien.com/roller/abien/entry/simplest_possible_pojo_injection_example)). He could have just removed `new Employee()` and the container should handle it.

Comment: removing new Employee() did not work. Error was still there. Creating a new instance of the Entity class instead of injecting it works as Tiny suggested. Although I cant tell if it working 100% as code still does not write to database but deploys without error .

Comment: Thanks for reporting back, @workingman. I don't know why that didn't work in your case, and Paul's solution is more conventional anyhow until you have need of CDI. Just keep in mind that if you need to inject a POJO, you can. Here's another reference, this time right from the [official tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/cdi-basic005.htm).